# Search function with get and selector

Tags: php, .htaccess, search, get

Im sorry if the title isnt exactly right, but Im not sure what exactly I want (well, how to tell it in english).

Basically I have one input field, where somebody can type some text and push enter/button to search the DB for it.
That form redirrects him to site.com/search.php?search=my+dumb+text
But I want to have there a selector (it will be drop down select), so they can lookup by Title or User and I want search URL to look like this:

site.com/search.php?user=dumb+name
site.com/search.php?title=weird+title

Just for clarification: I DONT want URL to be: site.com/rearch.php?user=dumb+name&type=user
Othervise I wouldnt have to ask there.

Is that possible without using JS or sending form as POST and then redirrecting them to search.php file?

Thats how it looks now:

```
<div class='search'>
    <form method='get' action='search.php'>
    <select name='type'>
        <option value='title'>Title IMG</option>
        <option value='user'>User IMG</option>
    </select>
    <input type='text' name='search' value='$search' placeholder='Search' class='search-field'><input type='submit' value='s' class='search-button'>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `site.com/search.php?user=dumb+name&title=weird+title`?

Comment: sidenote if `value='$search'` is from PHP (assuming because of the `'` quotes everywhere) then your open to [XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)

Comment: Jurik: thats what I dont want. I want URL to be user=something or title=something, not both.
Loz: Basically I need help with HTML, just ignore the PHP stuff there, it has nothing to do with my needs :)

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB I dont fully understand why you want to force the URLs to be like that, can you explain why you are doing this? perhaps you might want to look into rewrite rules? Although you will still have trouble getting the HTML form working as you want without JS.

Comment: Its mostly just for cosmetic look of the URL. Everything is working, I just wanted it to look better tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others pointed out what I hoped isnt true: Its impossible without redirect so I used the .htaccess to get it done.

Here is the form code:

```
<div class='search'>
    <form method='get' action='search.php'>
        <select name='type' class='search-select'>
            <option value='replay' ".(isset($_GET['replay']) ? 'selected' : '').">Replays</option>
            <option value='player' ".(isset($_GET['player']) ? 'selected' : '').">Users</option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' name='search' value='$search' placeholder='Search' class='search-field'>
        <input type='submit' value='s' class='search-button'>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

### .htaccess version

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=player&search=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^search.php$ /search.php?player=%1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^search.php?player=%1$ /search.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=replay&search=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^search.php$ /search.php?replay=%1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^search.php?replay=%1$ /search.php [L]
```

---

### PHP version

```
if (isset($_GET['type'])){
    if ($_GET['type'] == "player"){
        header("location:/search.php?player=".$_GET['search']);
        exit();
    }elseif($_GET['type'] == "replay"){
        header("location:/search.php?replay=".$_GET['search']);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want is maybe a radio to let the user select which type of search he wants:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="user">User<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="title">Title
```

this way you would get queries like ?search=A+B+C&type=user

this way its more flexible than changing the "search" parameter to something else

it is not possible to dynamically change the path to submit the form to or the field names in the form without js.

Comment: Thats exactly what I dont want. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: then as I mentioned in the answer, it is not possible without js, period.

Comment: Ok, so you just confirmed what I tought. I dont want to use JS tho, so maybe post and redirrect. Or both (js as main and post as backup).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='search'>
<?php echo "<form method='get' action='search.php?title= ".input_filter(INPUT_GET, 'search');." '>" ?>
<select name='type'>
    <option value='title'>Title IMG</option>
    <option value='user'>User IMG</option>
</select>
<input type='text' name='search' value='$search' placeholder='Search' class='search-field'><input type='submit' value='s' class='search-button'>
</form>
</div>
```

Try this code, let me know if it worked :D.

Comment: I dont even have to try it to know that it wont work. I want that TITLE part to be dynamic and be dependant on what user has choosen in drop-down menu. So there would be title or user, not always only one.